# Relation between axiom of foundation and constructible set

Tags: set-theory

I have the following problem:
In my lecures, the professor states the following theorem:

If ZFC is consistent then ZFC+V=L is consistent. (where L are the constructible set).

My question is : in ZFC we have the axiom of foundation that implies that V=WF. The previous theorem implies that V=L=WF? It is true that the well founded sets are equal to the constructible one? If we look at each step $L_{\alpha}$ is smaller than $V_{\alpha}$...

Comment: See Keith Devlin, [The Joy of Sets: Foundamentals of Contemporary Set Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Joy-Sets-Fundamentals-Contemporary-Undergraduate/dp/0387940944/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1402317680&sr=1-1-fkmr0&keywords=Keith+Devlin+The+Joy+of+Sets+Foundamentals+of+Contemporary+Set+Theory) (2nd ed : 1993), page 126 : **Theorem 5.3.1** : In the system $ZF + (V = L)$ Every set can be well-ordered.

Comment: If $V=WF$ then the assumption $V=L$ of course implies the triple equality. However, the triple equality is not necessarily true: It is consistent with $V=WF$ that $V\ne L$. The fact that many $L_\alpha$ are strictly smaller than the corresponding $V_\alpha$ plays no role in the equality $V=L$.

Comment: You have a theorem that says $(V=L)^{L}$, i.e. "L thinks it can serve as a universe for set theory". Hence you also have $(L=WF)^{L}$ here. But it doesn't answer the question of whether $L=WF$. To say it in a different way, if the universe for our set theory was the constructible sets then all the well founded sets are constructible.